# Change YouCompleteMe GetType popup position?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

[image]

The interactive GetType popup is a great feature, but I would love to set it so it spawns beneath the cursor, due to the fact that I sometimes need to read the above lines to know what parameters to give the function below.
I've searched the docs for an option but couldn't find any that references the position of popups. 
Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better off asking them; there may be a config variable. Otherwise you’ll have to adjust the code